# Swagger data validation with allOf and additional properties

Tags: swagger, ajv

Need help to solve a swagger definiton schema using allOf and additionalProperties: false

**Here my JSON Schema**

```
"deliveryContact": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "additionalProperties": false,
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "string",
              "maxLength": 1024
            },
            "phone": {
              "type": "string",
              "maxLength": 24
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/address"
        }
      ]
    },
    "address": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "address": {
          "type": "string",
          "maxLength": 1024
        },
        "postalCode": {
          "type": "string",
          "maxLength": 12
        },
        "city": {
          "type": "string",
          "maxLength": 512
        },
        "state": {
          "type": "string",
          "maxLength": 512
        }
      }
    },
```

**Sample data**

```
                   delivery: {
                        address: 'my address',
                        postalCode: 'my postalCode',
                        city: 'my city',
                        state: 'my state',
                        name: 'my name',
                        phone: 'my phone'
                    },
```

I use AJV 6.10.0 to validate my data, but I think I have a wrong schema definition.
With Ajv options :

```
        ajv = require('ajv')({
            allErrors: true,
            verbose: true,
            removeAdditional: false,
        });
```

Actually, I have 6 errors which warn of additional properties for each property

During validation of the first object in allOf (name and phone), validation found the error on (address, postalCode, city and state)

If I remove additionalProperties of the first allOf object (name, phone), during validation of address schema, the validation found the error on (name and phone)

How can I solve my schema definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it works, I have update your data structure to be more logical, see below :

**JSON Schema**

```js
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "delivery"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "delivery": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "required": [
        "name",
        "phone",
        "address"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "maxLength": 1024
        },
        "phone": {
          "type": "string",
          "maxLength": 24
        },
        "address": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/address"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "address": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "address": {
          "type": "string",
          "maxLength": 1024
        },
        "postalCode": {
          "type": "string",
          "maxLength": 12
        },
        "city": {
          "type": "string",
          "maxLength": 512
        },
        "state": {
          "type": "string",
          "maxLength": 512
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Sample data**

```js
{
  "delivery": {
    "address": {
      "address": "myaddress",
      "postalCode": "mypostalCode",
      "city": "mycity",
      "state": "mystate"
    },
    "name": "myname",
    "phone": "myphone"
  }
}
```

If you want to test it, you can do that here : https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/